# NSIS dism enable NetFx3 error 11 windows 2012

Tags: .net-3.5, nsis, dism

I want to enable .net3.5 in nsis installer in windows 2012.
I used next code:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'cmd /c %windir%\system32\dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All'
```

But it return error 11.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2NAq.png)

my dism log file: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E82PZ.png)

I run it on virtual machine, where I have only one user - administrator.
If I run this command directly in cmd - everything ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells you what the problem is. It can't use the 32-bit version for whatever reason.

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include x64.nsh

Section
${If} ${IsWow64}
  StrCpy $0 $windir\sysnative
${Else}
  StrCpy $0 $sysdir
${EndIf}
nsExec::ExecToStack 'cmd /c $0\dism.exe /Online ......'
Pop ...
Pop ...
SectionEnd
```